# While transferring local server work to live server in Odoo/OpenERP using postgreSql as a database? It is showing error

Tags: xml, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I had made many modifications like creating new views, models, menu items. I was working on the local server and I shifted newly created views, models, etc. on the server.

I took backup through pgAdminIII and when I transferred,

1. `Record data does not exist in odoo`.
2. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined`.

[image: Error Snapshot]

Comment: I took backup through pgAdminIII and restore it on the server but it showing some error and saying `Record data does not exist`.

Comment: Is the error appearing on your local or the live server? Can you provide more information on exactly how to dumped out the database, and uploaded it to the server? Did you include the file store as well?

Comment: It is appearing when I am uploading on the server. I am dumping from pgsql. No we didn't use filestore